# Library NuGet configuration is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-1.0

VS2015 Update 3.

I created a plain .net core class library.
Right-click on Project->References-> Manage Nuget packages
throws the following error?

What is missing?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Nuget.Config file in your project folder?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Try the following:**

1. **Restart VS** and see if this fixes your problem. (Close + Reopen Solution might work as well)
2. If restarting didn't help, try to delete nuget.config, explained below.

---

**Previous solution from year 2012**:

At the time I wrote this, the below approach worked for me:

Just delete the nuget.config which resides here:

```
%AppData%/Nuget/Nuget.config
```

or the nuget.config in your solution folder, if there is any.

A new one will be created automatically again, when you click on

> Manage Nuget Packages

Or try to delete the nuget.config in your solution folder.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You say %AppData%/Nuget/Nuget.config
In what context d you get %AppData%
I did a search under my projectfolder for Nuget.config and didn't find anything.

Comment: ah, Windows button + R opens the RUN dialog and there you enter `%AppData%/Nuget/`

Comment: OK thanks.
I solved it another way:
Created a new solution with a dummy UWP project.
Added a package to it.
Then added the original project to this new solution and wala!
Was able to add Nuget packages to it.

Comment: I just simply restart my Visual Studio and it is working like magic. Deleted the nuget.config but it was still not working,

Comment: Different causes different solutions ;-)

Comment: Restarting visual studio was exactly what fixed it for me... deleting the NuGet.config %AppData% did not help, also the content of the config was correct anyway.

Comment: Restarting fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Also helps in VS 2019

Comment: The venerable, undisputed advice: "Turn it off, turn it back on again"

Comment: I just closed my solution (from File menu Close Solution), and re-opened it, and it worked as well. Thanks!