# VS17 - NuGet Config invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I get this error that my NuGet config was supposed valid and it tells me to run a NuGet Restore, which I did many times, but it still doesn't manage to run the website. The problem is, that I cannot get into the NuGet Manager either, because VS just tells me that my config was invalid before closing the dialogue all together.

[image]

**References:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Anyone of you ever experienced this? How can I get at least back to editing my packages?

Comment: Does your project have a pacakges.config file? If so, please open it and check for XML syntax errors.  Next to "show output from", do you have "package manager" as an option? if so, check it for error messages. If not, try downloading nuget.exe from nuget.org, and run a restore from the command line and see if the error message helps (check different verbosity options if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to

1. Delete the nuget.config file at %AppData%/Nuget
2. Close the Solution and Re-Open

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340901/1249386

Answer (score 2):

> VS17 - NuGet Config invalid

(According to the error messages, we could not give the most direct correct answer for this issue, we can only give you some troubleshootings. In order to avoid losing contact in the round-trip comments, I post those troubleshootings as answer instead of comments.)

- update Visual Studio to the latest version.
- Check if there is any `nuget.config` in your solution, if yes, please open it and check for XML syntax errors or you can delete it.
- Create a new blank project check if this issue still persist, if yes, try to re-install the nuget package manager.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove-Item $env:APPDATA\Nuget\Nuget.config
```

Is the one-liner powershell version of @Sigar Dave.